# Passing value to typescript arrow function

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5

I am attempting to write a javascript function in typescript - however I'm finding it impossible to search for how to achieve it.
This is the javascript code I want to convert to typescript

```
var file = files[i];
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (function(f) {
    return function(e) {
    };
})(file);
```

The closest I have got is but I'm not sure how to pass the (file) like above:

```
var file = files[i];
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = (file: any) => {
    return (loadEvent: any) => {
    }
}
```

Comment: Typescript is Javascript: `... = ((file: any) => { ...})(file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
var file = files[i];
var reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = ((f: any) => {
    return (e: any) => {
        // some code
    };
})(file);
```